# Write output to only one line in txt file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My program writes the output correctly to the txt file but it puts the info on 2 lines instead of only one line.

Presently it writes it as:

```
Item name

User's name  Date  Time
```

I would like it to write it as:

```
Item name  User's name  Date  Time
```

I have not been able to figure out why it is putting the info on 2 lines.

The code I am using to write to the file is:

```
def write_to_file(self, nm):

    date = datetime.now().strftime('   %Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S')

    with open('user_sig.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(nm + self.ent.get() + date + '\n')
        f.close()
```

'nm' get the information from the button that was pressed and 'self.ent.get() get the User's name that they type in the text box. Other than not printing on one line, everything works correctly.

Comment: Obviously, ``nm`` ends with a newline.  Look at the code that produces that parameter.

Comment: what is `self.ent`? Is it a `Text` widget or an `Entry` widget, or something else?

Comment: 'nm' is the name of the button that the user presses. It is generated from a txt file that lists all of the items in the category that they selected. Each item in the txt file is on a separate line. Is the button retaining a newline tag from the txt file? If so, is there a way to remove it in the code? Or do I have to change the txt file and list them with a comma between each item?

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry, yes it is a 'Entry' widget not a 'Text' widget

Comment: it seems `nm` has `\n` at the end - so you have to remove it - ie. `nm = nm.strip()`

Comment: bottom line: the code you're writing has a newline. Neither python nor tkinter will add newlines behind your back (except the `Text` widget which guarantees a newline as the last character in the widget). Since you're not using a `Text` widget, the newline is being added by code you aren't showing us. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and do what it suggests.

Comment: @furas your answer is what i needed. I added the code to the `def` code and it works correctly now. If you want to write your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `nm` has `\n` at the end - so you have to remove it - ie.

```
nm = nm.strip()
```